# How do I clear the cookies in urllib.request (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

Looking through the docs my first guess was that I call urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor().cookiejar.clear(), however that didn't work. My next guess is maybe I need to subclass it and build/install it with an opener? I don't know how to do that, I can if need be of course, but it really seems like overkill for what I feel should be such a simple operation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default, `urllib.request` won't store any cookies, so there is nothing to clear.  If you build an `OpenerDirector` containing and `HTTPCookieProcessor` instance as one of the handlers, you have to clear the `cookiejar` of this instance.  [Example from the docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/http.cookiejar.html#examples):

```
import http.cookiejar, urllib.request
cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
r = opener.open("http://example.com/")
```

If you want to clear the cookies in `cj`, just call `cj.clear()`.

The call `urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor().cookiejar.clear()` you tried will create a new `HTTPCookieProcessor` instance which will have an empty `cookiejar`, clear the `cookiejar` (which is empty anyway) and drop the whole thing again, since you don't store references to any of the created objects -- so in short, it will do nothing.

Comment: Perfect. Turns out my problem was in parsing the html, not reading it, so I fixed it, but still I'll need to know this for the future.